# Custom exception handling can not run in Ubuntu but Dev C can

Tags: c++

When i use this code bellow: exception error is not print out screen when I using g++ in Ubuntu but when i change to Dev C in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

//Define Class for exception error
  class NoBinaryNumber: public logic_error{
  private:
    string s;
    int x;
  public:
    NoBinaryNumber(string msg,int x) : logic_error(msg){
            s = msg; this->x=x;
    }

    const char* what() const throw(){
            ostringstream a;
        a.str("");
          a <<  s << " is wrong at position "<< x;
        if(a)
          return a.str().c_str();
        else
          return "";    
    }
    ~NoBinaryNumber() throw(){};
  };

  class BinaryStringToNumber{
  public:
    int number;
    BinaryStringToNumber(string s){
        number=0;
        for (int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--){
            if ((s[i]=='1')||(s[i]=='0')){
                number=number+(s[i]-'0')*pow(2,i);
            }
            else{
                throw NoBinaryNumber(s,s.length()-i);
          cout << "alala" ;
            }
        }
    }
  };

int main(){
//Using customer exception error
  try{
    BinaryStringToNumber a("2");
    cout << a.number << endl;
  }
  catch (NoBinaryNumber& e){
    cout << e.what() << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The result shoud be: "2 is wrong at position 1"

Comment: I using g++ filename.cpp in ubuntu to excute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `what()` function, you are creating an object (ostringstream), which is destructed at the end of this function call, and trying to access its content (`a.str().c_str()`) outside of `what()` function. This is an undefined behaviour (UB) and the fact that DevC++ is showing is just because it is an UB.

To solve this, I suggest you to create your message at constructor call and use `what()` just to show this message. Something like this:

```
class NoBinaryNumber: public logic_error{
private:
    string s;
    int x;
public:
    NoBinaryNumber(string msg,int x) : logic_error(msg){
        s = msg + " is wrong at position " << std::to_string(x);
        this->x=x;
    }

    const char* what() const throw(){
              return msg.c_str();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you Amadeus, I have sloved the prob.